# using vector as function output

Tags: c++, function, vector

I'm trying to write a code shows all the numbers with the following characteristics:

- the number itself is a prime number.
- for each digit removed from the right the remaining number should still be a prime number.

Considering the number 293 for example: 293 itself is a prime number if we delete the digit on the right we have 29 which is still a prime number, and if we delete the right digit again we have 2 which is still prime.

I'm trying to write a code that gets the integer n<=8 from the user and shows all the n-digit numbers that have the characteristics stated above. My algorithm is to write a recursive function (`show`) that returns the vector `v`.

If `n=1` then it just shows the numbers 2-3-5-7... if `n!=1` it should call `show(n-1)` and multiply all the generated numbers by 10 and add them up with odd numbers... then it should check if the new number is prime. If so it should be added to the vector.

My problem is the code only works for `n=1`. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int a)
{
    int i, p = 0;
    if (a == 1)
        return false;
    else
    {
        for (i = a - 1; i > sqrt(a); i--)
            if (a % i == 0)
                p++;
        if (p != 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}

vector<int> show(int n)
{
    vector<int> v;
    int i, j;
    if (n == 1)
    {
        v.push_back(2);
        v.push_back(3);
        v.push_back(5);
        v.push_back(7);
    }
    else
    {
        show(n - 1);

        if (n != 1)
            for (i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
            {
                for (j = 1; j <= 9; j += 2)
                    if (isPrime((v.at(i) * 10) + j))
                        v.at(i) = (v.at(i) * 10) + j;
            }
    }
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    int n, s = 0, i;

    cin >> n;
    show(n);
    for (i = 0; i < show(n).size(); i++)
        cout << show(n).at(i) << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: You really should save the return value of `show` in `main` instead of calculating the primes `n+2` times.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to comments on question, take a look at the `show(n - 1)` line. Shouldn't you be saving the return value: `v = show(n - 1)`?

Also, it will be better to pass the vector as a reference, in this way you avoid the copy of vector's content (in your case it doesn't have much impact since vector will not grow too much, but imagine using large values for `n`).